# SQL injection protection in Expression

Tags: java, couchbase, sql++

I am trying to make my queries SQL injection proof. I am using couchbase expression to build the query with user input

```
  private GroupByPath getSearchStatement(SearchParams searchParams) {
        String bucketName = asyncBucket.name();
        Expression expression = x("sample_id").eq(s(searchParams.getSampleId()));
        String selectStatement = bucketName + ".*";
        return select(selectStatement)
                .from(bucketName)
                .where(expression);
    }
```

Is this code SQL injection safe? Or I have to do anything extra.

Comment: This doesn't look like Couchbase to me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is though. `GroupByPath` is a Couchabse Java sdk interface - http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.2.8/com/couchbase/client/java/query/dsl/path/GroupByPath.html

Comment: By the looks of it, depends on whether [`s(..)`](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.3.5/com/couchbase/client/java/query/dsl/Expression.html#s-java.lang.String...-) properly escapes the input. Would assume so but it's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks good enough to prevent sql injection. Parameterized queries should be another way to do it and more flexible for prepared queries.

A simple example would be

`N1qlQuery.parameterized("select * from myBucket where sample_id = $1", JsonArray.from(searchParams.getSampleId()));`

It can be either positional/named parameters.